# How to get source with apt-get source in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, aptitude, ubuntu-8.04

I need to install pure-ftpd from source and need to do `apt-get source pure-ftpd` but I get this message:
`E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`

I found some documentation about this for Debian on `http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-basico.en.html#s-sources.list` but what URIs should I add to sources.list for Ubuntu and if I want the source for pur-ftpd?

**EDIT:** I found some URIs on [Sources.List For Ubuntu Hardy Heron (8.04)](http://tuxicity.wordpress.com/sourceslist-for-ubuntu-hardy-heron-810/)
So I added these lines to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy main restricted universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-updates main restricted
universe
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The source lines look exactly the same as the normal package lines, they just say `deb-src` instead of `deb`.

so just copy the ones you have now and change them to be `deb-src`.

**Update** - 
You may also need to apt-get update after adding the deb-src lines.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to upvote your answer, but since I'm new user I cannot upvote.

Comment: You may also need to `apt-get` update after adding the `deb-src` lines (as Sunny had mentioned below)

Comment: Yes! Mine did not work even after uncommenting all the `deb-src` lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` like other answers suggested. I had to manually copy the first 2 `deb` lines and change them to `deb-src`, then `apt-get update`, then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you open /etc/apt/sources.list file, you will see commented out lines (starts with #) which have "source" on them.

Uncomment the one for universe (thats where pure-ftpd is). Then save and close the file.

Run:

```
> sudo apt-get update
```

And then you'll be able to download the sources.

Comment: No, I have no commented out lines there :( only three uncommented deb lines and no deb-src lines. I'm using Ubuntu Server 8.04 LTS.

Comment: Would have been nice if you have put this info in your original question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
apt-cache show programName
```